# how does 'Brace expansion' work in Bash?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

There's a example in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

```
$ echo {file1,file2}\ :{\ A," B",' C'}  
file1 : A file1 : B file1 : C file2 : A file2 : B file2 : C
```

How does this work?
I change this command like below:

```
$ echo {file1,file2}\  {\ A," B",' C'}  
file1  file2   A  B  C
$ echo {file1,file2}\ -{\ A," B",' C'}  
file1 - A file1 - B file1 - C file2 - A file2 - B file2 - C
```

Why the first command does not work like the command in the example?
Help!

I know that I have introduced an extra space. If change the an extra space to something else(colon,dash etc), then everything is fine. 
There's no details about commands like: echo {" A"," B",' C'}\ {" D"," E",' F'}\ {" G"," H",' I'} in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html. I wanna know more about it.

Comment: If you *escape* added space, everything is fine again: `echo {file1,file2}\ \ {\ A," B",' C'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the first command does not work like the command in the example?

Because you have introduced an extra space:

```
#                     |==> This is it!
#                     |
$ echo {file1,file2}\  {\ A," B",' C'}
file1  file2   A  B  C
$ echo {file1,file2}\ {\ A," B",' C'}    # This is probably what you expected!
file1  A file1  B file1  C file2  A file2  B file2  C
```

The extra space causes the shell to first expand `{file1,file2}` and then `{\ A," B",' C'}`.

---

Quoting from [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

> Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional preamble,
>   followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a seqeunce
>   expression between a pair of braces, followed by an optional
>   postscript. The preamble is prefixed to each string contained within
>   the braces, and the postscript is then appended to each resulting
>   string, expanding left to right.

When you introduce a space after a brace expansion (a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> followed by *two* spaces is a space!), the following token is no longer considered a *postscript* and is expanded separately.

Comment: Thanks. I know that I have introduced an extra space. If change the an extra space to something else(colon,dash etc), then everything is fine. There's no details about `echo {" A"," B",' C'}\ {" D"," E",' F'}\ {" G"," H",' I'}` in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html. I wanna know more about it.

Comment: @android_su See the edit above.  I hope it clarifies!

Comment: @android_su Try this: `echo {file,image}{0..4}.{raw,png,txt}`... You could make your tries...

Comment: @android_su: The difference is that an unquoted space separates arguments, whereas a colon or dash does not. For example, `touch A B` has two separate arguments, `A`, and `B`, so it creates two files, whereas `touch A:B` has only one argument, `A:B`, so it creates only one file.